# How to pass option to python when I'm running a jupyter notebook on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've created a virtual environment using `venv` and I'm using such environment in Visual Studio Code to run a jupyter notebook.

Now, my code stops running and from the log I can read 2 warnings: one of which is

```
warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

Let's suppose I want to pass `-Xfrozen_modules=off` to python to see what happens, how can I do it? I mean: I'm not running python from command line, I'm just pressing Shift+Enter in Visual Studio Code to execute the code cells of my notebook; how can I pass option to python in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the ***kernel.json*** file of the jupyter kernel under the virtual environment folder. It should be in the following path

```
...\venv\share\jupyter\kernels\python3\kernel.json
```

Open the **kernel.json** file and add the `-Xfrozen_modules=off` parameter in `"argv"`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just put `"jupyter.jupyterCommandLineArguments": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"],` in your workspace's [.vscode/settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)?